# How to define a string verbatim in vim

Tags: vim

Is there a way to define a string with newline character,
verbatim in vim. In short what I am looking for is an vim
equivalent of the following bash command

```
printf " 
/* -.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.
* File Name :
* Last Modified :
* Created By :  
_._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._.*/
"
```

I can do it by (a) printing every line individually, (b) add "^M" to each line, (c) read the text from a file using :r, all of which are a little cumbersome. Is there a clean way like bash's printf in vim.

I want to add this to my ~/.vim/after/c.vim so that
whenever I open a new c file the above is added to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to add this to my
>   ~/.vim/after/c.vim so that whenever I
>   open a new c file the above is added
>   to the file.

Without plugins, vim suggests doing this by reading in the contents of a skeleton file for filetypes of your choosing.

From `:help skeleton`:

```
To read a skeleton (template) file when opening a new file:
  :autocmd BufNewFile  *.c       0r ~/vim/skeleton.c
  :autocmd BufNewFile  *.h       0r ~/vim/skeleton.h
  :autocmd BufNewFile  *.java    0r ~/vim/skeleton.java
```

This is entirely non interactive.  There are many plugins that provide and enhance this feature including the aforementioned mu-template as well as [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540).

Comment: Thanks. snipMate looks useful

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
:map foo i/* -.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.
* File Name :
* Last Modified :
* Created By :  
_._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._.*/
```

in ~.vimrc (Linux)

Notice the "i" in the beginning. Now you type foo in
command mode to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, the usual approach is to rely on template loader/expander plugins (TEP), that are triggered on `BufNewFile` event -- there is no standard pathanme for this kind of feature (i.e. `.vim/after/c.vim`, `.vim/after/plugin/c.vim` or `.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim` are no good).

Moreover, some TEP will be able to do much more than just filling-in a default header for all your files. For instance, [mu-template](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/muTemplate#C_&_C++) (I'm maintaining) will provide default (customizable) header-guards (in header files case), or include any matching header-file found (in source files case). (File headers can also be overriden for each different project).